# Capistrano looking for releases / files that don't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

Having a bit of a rough time deploying a rails 3.1 app - things seem to be working but I'm getting weird errors:

```
    *** [err :: 97.107.134.41] find: `/home/deploy/myapp/releases/20120208030228/public/images'
*** [err :: 97.107.134.41] : No such file or directory
*** [err :: 97.107.134.41] find: `/home/deploy/myapp/releases/20120208030228/public/stylesheets': No such file or directory
*** [err :: 97.107.134.41] 
*** [err :: 97.107.134.41] find: `/home/deploy/myapp/releases/20120208030228/public/javascripts': No such file or directory
    command finished in 73ms
```

firs off, there is no "20120208030228" release.  Secondly, why is it looking for public/javascripts etc when it's a Rails 3 App?

EDIT - found the answer here:  [Capistrano for Rails 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774671/capistrano-for-rails-3-1)

Added "set :normalize_asset_timestamps, false" to the deploy.rb file and the errors are gone!

Comment: What version of Capistrano are you using? It may not be Rails 3.1-aware.

Comment: I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774671/capistrano-for-rails-3-1  I added set :normalize_asset_timestamps, false to the deploy.rb file and that fixed it!

Comment: @fatfrog - If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Comment: @DreadPirateShawn I'm cool with giving the answer to Steve! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying the answer from the comments in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

> I found the answer here: [Capistrano for Rails 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774671/capistrano-for-rails-3-1) I added set :normalize_asset_timestamps, false to the deploy.rb file and that fixed it!

~ link per [fatfrog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/312342/fatfrog) to a helpful question by [Steve Harman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/738187/steve-harman)